Update the data in the Room database does not work
CRUD operations such as delete, add, select work quite correctly, but updates do not update anything in the database at all. I'm new to all this.
I am attaching the available code:
@Entity
@Entity(
    tableName = "book",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = User::class,
            parentColumns = ["user_id"],
            childColumns = ["user_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.NO_ACTION,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.NO_ACTION
        )
    ]
)
data class Books(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "book_id")
    val bookId: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    val userId: Int? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url")
    val imageUrl: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    val title: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
    val author: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "genre")
    val genre: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val description: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    val status: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "rating")
    val rating: Double? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "creation_date")
    val creationDate: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
)

@Dao
@Update
suspend fun updateBook(book: Books)

@Database
@Database(entities = [User::class, Books::class, Chapters::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun booksDao(): BooksDao
    abstract fun chaptersDao(): ChaptersDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = INSTANCE ?:
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            INSTANCE ?:
            createDatabase(context).also {
                INSTANCE = it
            }
        }

        private fun createDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "app_database"
            ).build()
    }
}

Repo
suspend fun updateBooks(books: Books) = db.booksDao().updateBook(books)

ViewModel
fun updateBooks(books: Books) =
        viewModelScope.launch {
            booksRepository.updateBooks(books)
        }

Navigator
composable("change_book/{bookId}",
                    arguments = listOf(navArgument("bookId") {type = NavType.IntType})
                ) {backStackEntry ->
                    backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("bookId")
                        ?.let { ChangeBook(navController, database, userViewModel, it, updateBooks = { booksViewModel.updateBooks(it) }) }
                }

Composable fun ChangeBook
val books = currentBooks?.let {
                            Books(
                                it.bookId,
                                imageUrl = updatedImage,
                                title = updatedTitle,
                                author = updatedAuthor,
                                genre = updatedGenre,
                                description = updatedDescription
                            )
                        }
                        if (books != null) {
                            updateBooks(books)
                        }

Everything is recorded successfully in the updateImage data and so on (the data in them is correct)
I changed @update to @query.

At first glance I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Can you confirm that the repository's updateBooks function sends the expected Books object (with the changes you want to see) to the Dao?
